# Test loss seems to be increased after 20 epochs

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

I trained MNIST using 8 layers fully connected neural network (tensorflow) and got my result as shown below. May I know why the test loss increased after the 20 epoch? Is that due to overfitting? These are the network configurations:

```
L1: 1600 neurons
L2: 800 neurons
L3: 400 neurons
L4: 200 neurons
L5: 100 neurons
L6: 60 neurons
L7: 30 neurons
L8: 10 neurons
Optimizer: Adam (learning_rate = 0.001)
activation function: Relu
batch size: 64
dropout rate: 0.7
epoch:100
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have seen the benchmarks listed [here](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/), the author uses 2 layers each has 300 neurons and get a high accuracy. You have more neurons which will make the network easier overfitting, so first try to reduce neurons. And you use a large batch, which will make the network hard to convergence, then secondly try using little batch or use even smaller learning rate like `.0005`. The last thing is to try to use `LeakyRelu()` or `tanh()` or even `sigmoid()`, because `Relu()` function maybe dead at the late learning process.

Answer (score 4):

This is might very well be due to overfitting. In particular, note how the test *loss* increases but the test *accuracy* stays mostly the same (or even keeps increasing). This can arise from the model making wrong predictions (on the test set) with more and more certainty. I.e. it doesn't make more wrong predictions as time goes on (explaining the stable/increasing accuracy) but gets ever more confident in its currently wrong predictions (explaining the increasing cost).

This in turn could be due to the model overfitting on characteristics on the training data that don't generalize to the test data. This is particularly true for MNIST where overfitting to "spurious" features (such as single pixels) is common.